# I want to insert values dynamically to hash map

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var markerList1={};
var markerList=[];
```

and adding iterator values from the one for loop

```
function addSomething() // this function will multiple times from a for loop
    {

        image ='../css/abc/'+image[iterator]+'.png';
        var data = respData[iterator];
        var box = getbox(data);
        var markerOpts = {  
            position : coordinates[iterator],
            map      : map,
            icon     :image,
            title    :data[1],  
            id       : data[11]
        };

        var vmarks = new google.maps.Marker(markerOpts);

        markerList.push(vmarks);            
        markerList1[markerOpts.title].push(vmarks);
    }
```

whenever we call the function i want append the array's values to same index
markerList1[data[11]].push(vmarks);

but i'm not getting above result, when i markerList1[data[11]) then i'm getting only the last value i.e thirdvmark

i want output like this= markerList1[data[11]] = {firstvmark, secondvmark, thirdvmark};

Comment: there is no such thing as `{firstvmark, secondvmark, thirdvmark}`... `{}` is a key/value object, not an array

Comment: Do you have any error when you do `markerList1[data[11]].push(vmarks);`? If yes, what error?

Comment: @vsync please don't put your solution in the edit, now we can't see the original problem.

Comment: @Volune - I did no such thing. I organized his code in a readable manner without changing anything. I find it a bit rude of you.

Comment: @vsync Extracting the `newmarkerOpts` object and replacing `data[11]` by `markerOpts.title`. I'm not sure doing refactoring in an edit will help the author understand why this refactoring is good, or help people give an answer adapted to the author's programming level. Also now, the code is no longer coherent with  the text "_i want append the array's values to same index markerList1[data[11]].push(vmarks)_"

Comment: I gave him an an answer already, also what you're saying is opinion based, you are guessing here that the changes might or might not affect the answers here. well, I claim my changes help, by making the question more readable -> understanding the code faster & easier -> identifying the problem quicker -> more / better answers. Question **must** be kept readable and refactored at all times for higher-quality answers.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do `push` to an object `markerList1`, only to an array.

change this

```
markerList1[markerOpts.title].push(vmarks);`
```

To this

```
markerList1[markerOpts.title] = vmarks;
```

Answer (score 0):

`markerList1[data[11]]` is never initialized before you push something inside.

You can initialize it only once with a simple test:

```
if (! (data[11] in markerList1) ) {
    markerList1[data[11]] = [];
}
markerList1[data[11]].push(vmarks);
```

Or in a shorter and safer way:

```
markerList1[data[11]] = markerList1[data[11]] || [];
markerList1[data[11]].push(vmarks);
```

(And please put `data[11]` in a variable)

Comment: Can i store multiple values in one index of an object,

Comment: based on id of user i have to hide/remove the multiple markers

Comment: `markerList1[data[11]]` will be an array, so for each id you can put as many markers as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
        var vmarks = new google.maps.Marker(markerOpts);
        markerList.push(vmarks);//you already pushing vmarks to array            
        markerList1[markerOpts.title]=markerList;//assign array to your markerList1 map
```